# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

ClassCode Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClassCode](
[SchoolCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[ClassCode] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
[ClassName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[ClassRange] [int] NOT NULL,
[ClassDuration] numeric(38,2) NOT NULL,
[UserID] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[RecordDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,  
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ClassCode] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SchoolCode] ASC,
    [ClassCode] ASC,
    [ClassRange]
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

ExamDeclaration Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExamDeclaration](
[SchoolCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[ClassCode] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
[ExamCode] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
[RegistationFess] numeric(38,2) NOT NULL,
[RegistatinStartDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[RegistatinEndDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[ExamStartDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[UserID] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[RecordDate] [smalldatetime] NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ExamDeclaration] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SchoolCode] ASC,
    [ClassCode] ASC,
    [ExamCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExamDeclaration]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ExamDeclaration_ClassCode] FOREIGN KEY([ClassCode])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ClassCode] ([ClassCode])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExamDeclaration] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ExamDeclaration_ClassCode]
GO
```

I am trying to set Foreign key ClassCode

but got this error

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 2 There are no primary or candidate
>   keys in the referenced table 'dbo.ClassCode' that match the
>   referencing column list in the foreign key
>   'FK_ExamDeclaration_ClassCode'. Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors. Msg 4917, Level 16,
>   State 0, Line 2 Constraint 'FK_ExamDeclaration_ClassCode' does not
>   exist. Msg 4916, Level 16, State 0, Line 2 Could not enable or disable
>   the constraint. See previous errors.

What is the problem in these two tables?

thank you..

Comment: You can't reference only a portion of a composite key with a foreign key. The primary key in ClassCode is 3 columns but you are trying to only reference the ClassCode as your foreign key in ExamDeclaration.

Comment: You must have claacode as pk or unique index in reference table classcode. You have not such pk.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreign key must match exactly the primary key!
If you declare the primary key like this **PK(X int,Y int, Z int)**, then the FK must be declared like this: **FK (a int, b int, c int) references MyTable(X,Y,Z)**.

In your case, your Pk is (SchoolCode, ClassCode, ClassRange). This means you should declare FK like this:

`ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExamDeclaration]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ExamDeclaration_ClassCode] FOREIGN KEY(SchoolCode, ClassCode, ClassRange)
REFERENCES [dbo].[ClassCode] (SchoolCode, ClassCode, ClassRange)
GO`

Modify your table ExamDeclaration, add column 'ClassRange'.